# Update an attribute with value from loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an app to store sport games, for this all users will be placed in seperated leagues. I've set up a many to many for this but when a user looks at the application he can only see all the info from it's current_league.

Now I'm trying to make a loop with all the leagues a user is in and the user should be able to click the league to change it's active league.

Routes

```
  resources :users do
    member do
      post :change_current_league

    end
  end
```

UserController

```
def change_current_league
    @user = current_user
    @user.update(:current_league_id, params[:league_id])
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully changed your active league"
end
```

View

```
<% current_user.leagues.each do |l| %>


<%= link_to change_current_league_user_path(current_user, l), method: :post, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' do %>



                    <%= l.id %><%= l.league_name %><br>
<% end %>




<% end %>
```

What should I do to get this to work?

Sorry if its a bit of a noob question :P

EDIT:

```
def change_current_league
    @user = current_user
    @user.update_attribute(:current_league_id, 1)
    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully changed your active league"
end


  resources :users do
    member do
      patch :change_current_league

    end
  end
```

This is working but how do I get the correct league_id into the user controller?

EDIT2:

```
def change_current_league
    @league = League.find(params[:league_id])

    @user = current_user

    @user.update_attribute(:current_league_id, @league)

    redirect_to :back, :notice => "Successfully changed your active league"
end
```

Comment: You are updating user atrribute so its a put/patch request not post method

Comment: pass the league_id as a parameter with your link like this
<%= link_to change_current_league_user_path(current_user, current_league_id: l.id), method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' do %>

Comment: Okay thx. and now I've tried this in the usercontroller (check edit). But it updates the field to nil now..

Comment: what you get in your param hash ? at  usercontroller (check edit)

Comment: @user.update_attribute(current_league_id: params[:current_league_id])
replace with above line

Comment: Allright great! Thx for the advice!

Comment: If your issue is solved, I will convert this comments into answer please accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,
You are updating user attribute so its a put/patch request not post request.pass the league_id as a parameter with your link like this,

```
<%= link_to change_current_league_user_path(current_user, current_league_id: l.id), method: :patch, class: 'btn btn-default btn-sm' do %>
```

and in your usercontroller (check edit) replace with bellow line

```
@user.update_attribute(current_league_id: params[:current_league_id])
```